# Reduce number of unnecessary merge conflicts in PackageReference in csproj files

Tags: c#, git, csproj

I'm working on a (very) large C# project with a significant number of external packages. I'm trying mitigate the problem of unnecessary merge conflicts in *.csproj files caused by package updates.

The *new* style of `PackageReference` that has a `Version` attribute is very prone to merge conflicts if packages are updated on adjacent lines:

```
<PackageReference Include="Package1" Version="1.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Package2" Version="1.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Package3" Version="1.0.0" />
```

Given a csproj file with the above content, if one developer bumps the version of `Package1` and `Package3` while another bumps `Package2`, the two conflict. This requires unnecessary manual work although no real conflict has occurred - all three packages have been bumped.

So far, I explored three possible solutions, but haven't found a clear winner:

1. Setting a diff driver for *.csproj files using .gitattributes. However, none of the built-in diff drivers seem to produce a cleaner diff result (not surprising, given none of them is meant for csproj or even xml files).
2. Forcing the usage of the *old* style of `PackageReference`, in which `Version` isn't an attribute but an xml element: `<Version>1.0.0</Version>`. This causes significantly fewer conflicts due to the extra lines. However, I couldn't find a clear way of forcing VS/Rider/Nuget to use the old style, so we'd need to distribute a custom git hook to everyone working on the project to force it.
3. Distributing the most frequently updated packages to external `.targets` files, then importing these files using `<Import>`. This works, but requires custom tooling, especially for adding new references in a consistent manner. This also seems to (partially) break the "Manage NuGet" functionality of both VS (2022) and Rider, though that isn't a big deal.

Can anyone suggest other approaches or ways to improve on the ones above?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/MSBuildSdks/tree/main/src/CentralPackageVersions I used this a few years ago

Comment: Do you really change the package numbers often enough for this to be a problem? At a guess, I think you can duplicate the `<ItemGroup>` lines surrounding it so that you have multiple such groups, this should lessen the chance of it becoming a conflict.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Unfortunately, yes. There's a large number of developers working on the project, many of them bumping versions of external packages. So conflicts are frequent enough to be worth the effort.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Multiple `<ItemGroup>` is an interesting idea, but just like (2) and (3), requires extra tooling to enforce. It definitely can be done, but I was hoping for something simpler and more robust.

Comment: There's no support in IDEs or Git to do what you want. I don't really know if multiple ItemGroup's will work, I just seem to recall having a project file that I inspected that had such a thing, without Rider or Visual Studio seeming to care. However, to **ensure** you won't get this kind of situation, you're going to have to roll your own solution. I have been toying with the idea of some pre-merge-conflict-tool that would fix "known issues" before punting any remaining issues over to the real conflict handling tool. (to be continued)

Comment: (continued) I know that the way I have configured Beyond Compare 4 for Git is that if I ask git to handle conflicts by opening up Beyond Compare, if BC is able to automatically resolve the conflicts without my help, the tool fixes the files and then simply returns, continuing the merge conflict resolution process that Git is managing. My toy idea would be a similar tool in front of Beyond Compare, that would know "common scenarios" and have solutions for them, such as the kind of conflict you're describing.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yeah, I briefly considered resolving such conflicts automatically when they occurred using a "common scenarios" approach (with the most common scenario being a version bump of two adjacent, unrelated packages). But I'd much rather avoid the conflicts in the first place than resolve the conflicting results.

Comment: Unfortunately, unless you can separate the lines, or get a git merge tool that knows how to handle this, there's nothing you can do. Git will always consider changes on two branches on adjacent lines as potential conflicts, even if they're not really. This is just "better safe than sorry" kind of rule in play.

Comment: @DanielA.White That's a nice feature, thanks. But how does that help with conflicts? Bumping adjacent lines in `Packages.props` would still conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone in the same boat, we ended up going with [CentralPackageVersions](https://github.com/microsoft/MSBuildSdks/tree/main/src/CentralPackageVersions) with `packages.props` being in the "long" format in which `Version` is an element, not an attribute:

```
<PackageReference Update="Foo">
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

It's also worth pointing out that Microsoft recently introduced [Central Package Managemet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/central-package-management) which is supposed to be supported by Visual Studio and other tooling. However, it requires new versions of just about everything:

> The feature is available across all NuGet integrated tooling.
>
> - Visual Studio 2022 17.2 and later
> - .NET SDK 6.0.300 and later
> - .NET SDK 7.0.0-preview.4 and later
> - nuget.exe 6.2.0 and later